# Load formgroup data into a anchor tag

Tags: angular

I have something like this

```
 **<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" *ngIf="isEdit">
    <label for="url">URL</label>
    <input id="url" [formControl]="fg.url" class="form-control" type="text" />
  </div>**
```

Now I can see url data in the text box.How can I modify this code in the html file so I can see data as a clickable url link.I mean how can I use the anchor tag in this context.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I get correctly what you want to do. Just add the anchor tag and put in the value between these {{}}.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" *ngIf="isEdit">
  <label for="url">
    <a [href]="form.controls.url.value">{{form.controls.url.value}}</a>
  </label>
  <input id="url" [formControl]="fg.url" class="form-control" type="text" />
</div>
```